# jquery call back function

Tags: jquery, function, call, back

i have a form and it validates and submit successfully.
all i want is to call back function as "success" when the form has successfully submitted. here is what i have so far but no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1").validate({
        rules: {

                email1: {// compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true                 
                }
)};
$('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
                //document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = "Thank You!!"
            }); 
    });
```

here is my form input:

```
<input name="email1" size="22" type="text"/>
```

any ideas is greatly appreciated!

---

thanks for your responses. its not working well for me as i am trying to display "success" in this dhtml fadeout effect: http://dhtmlpopups.webarticles.org/fade-effects.php

i am pretty much stuck going in circles trying to find a way for the alert(success) to print out in the fade out.

any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error 'ajaxForm is not a function'? Did you remember to add a script tag referencing the ajaxForm jquery plugin? You need this, AFTER your script tag referencing the main jquery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
```

With src of course pointing to a real file. AjaxForm is not part of the jQuery core.

If that doesn't work, you could try substituting the $ jquery symbol with 'jQuery' (case sensitive!), to check if $ might be redefined in any of your other scripts.

Comment: yup, you are right. the only thing now is, it doesnt allow me to validate, it submit and returns alert(success), can i time it so that i can validate the form and then it can submit?

Answer (score 3):

I quickly browsed the [API](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) and found this. <strike>(tsk.. tsk)</strike>

**Sorry, but always remember to browse the API. It will save you a lot of pain.**

```
$('#form1').ajaxForm({
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

Comment: i get an error like this: Error: $("#form1").ajaxForm is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll need to submit via AJAX:

```
$("#form1").submit(function() {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit();
  return false;
});
```

See the [docs](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api).

Assuming you're already doing that, `ajaxForm()` (which only prepares it but doesn't submit it) can take any of the [`$.ajax` options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so:

```
$("#form1").ajaxForm({
  success: function() {
    alert("Thank you for your comment");
  }
});
```

Comment: i get an error like this: Error: $("#form1").ajaxForm is not a function